# svn: E155007: '/home/k/python/myproject_env/django-myproject/myproject' is not a working copy

Tags: python, django, svn

I have been building django project and I want to use Subversion for version control on Ubuntu.

As you know, I need to keep most of the projects in the repository, however, some files and directories should only stay locally and not be tracked.

So I went to my project directory and typed the following command.

**svn propedit svn:ignore myproject**

But exception has occurred like this.

> svn: E155007: '/home/k/python/myproject_env/django-myproject/myproject' is not a working copy

The path is ture that my app is located at */home/k/python/myproject_env/django-myproject/myproject*

The guide says that when I type the command above, this will open a temporary file in the editor, where I need to put the following file and directory patterns for Subversion to ignore. But it doesn't work.

I already found the solution, but there is no answer anywhere.

I would like to know the solution. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi. Daniel. I already commit the project on github. I'm well versed in git, but I have no idea of SVN. Just I wanna know how to use SVN. and wanna know the difference between git and svn. If you already know that, please tell me.

Comment: The difference betwee git and subversion is that most people were using subversion about 10 years ago while most people are now using git